# set window icon tkinter macosx

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, icons

This line works fine for my Windows program.

When i run this same file on the Mac OS X, I get a blank page instead of my icon.

Here is the windows line:

```
self.iconbitmap("Boss.ico")
```

I have searched relentlusly for an answer I want this icon to work on both platforms.  `self` is the root Tk window if your wondering if it's root or not.

**Note:**  I have tried using icns, .xbm , .gif by loading a photo image and setting thru window attributes all produce the same blank page on the mac.

Answer (score 3):

After  5 days of searching, and this post having been viewed at least 15 times I went directly to the tk/tcl documentation.  If I understand this correctly, apparently there is no way to properly set the icon for mac OS X without using special library or other sort of hacks.  It would be nice if there were a mac specific documentation for the tkinter library but alas there isn't that I have found.  here is the part of the documentation I found:

> wm iconphoto window ?-default? image1 ?image2 ...? Sets the titlebar
>   icon for window based on the named photo images. If -default is
>   specified, this is applied to all future created toplevels as well.
>   The data in the images is taken as a snapshot at the time of
>   invocation. If the images are later changed, this is not reflected to
>   the titlebar icons. Multiple images are accepted to allow different
>   images sizes (e.g., 16x16 and 32x32) to be provided. The window
>   manager may scale provided icons to an appropriate size. On Windows,
>   the images are packed into a Windows icon structure. This will
>   override an ico specified to wm iconbitmap, and vice versa.
>
> > On X, the images are arranged into the _NET_WM_ICON X property, which
> >     most modern window managers support. A wm iconbitmap may exist
> >     simultaneously. It is recommended to use not more than 2 icons,
> >     placing the larger icon first.
> >
> > On Macintosh, this currently does nothing.

if anyone has a working solution please post this.  I want to accomplish this so that any system can open a freshly installed python and run my application without installing any additional library.

Comment: It shocking that I reached the same conclusion and we are both in 2018?

Comment: Not at all 2019 now and yes I had a feeling it will take 10 more years to fix it lol.... by the time they fix it I will be able to write my own c# wrapper around it. or even c++ wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

@GarryHurst This is not a solution but I sort of get the idea now:

1. On Mac, TK decided that the icon will never appear on the window title bar.
2. Instead, it shows up as the app's Dock icon.

It's most probably a *by-design* or *won't fix* issue on their side.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing the icon of the file you are putting in the directory so setting  the file to be an app will set the window icon to be the icon of that app.
for example:
`root.iconbitmap("/Users/homedir./Desktop/Test apps/Clicker.app")`
[tk window with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJDJk.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have a coup. Why not change mind, like this.
The emoji library is enough to choose a good-looking icon.
We can do that.:-D

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcpbO.jpg)

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHJ3Y.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).